# "Aborted Client" occurs even though MySQL has resources left over

Tags: mysql, airflow

I'm using MySQL and my CPU usage is 10-15% and memory is about 3 out of 4 gigs.

MySQL is experiencing 40 aborted clients per minute.

Queries are being requested at around 200 per second.

I am using MySQL as the SystemDB for Apache Airflow, so it is difficult to reduce the requests.

Is there any way to resolve this? I need help.

Comment: Additional DB information request, please. 
OS, Version? 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*), sum(data_length), sum(index_length), sum(data_free) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: Please consider posting requested data to enable suggestions for improvement of Global Variable suggestions to reduce/eliminate your 40 aborted clients per minute.